# Heroku sais: "Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG" but it is set?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to setup a Django site on Heroku. I get this error message:

```
2017-10-07T21:03:33.416585+00:00 app[web.1]:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting 
LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define 
the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call 
settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

But if I run Heroku config, the var is set. Why is it not recognized?

```
=== dagenssalg Config Vars
DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC: 0
LOGGING_CONFIG:        off
```

Many answers in here mention the wsgi.py file, but I can't see anything wrong with that:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","dagenssalg.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any help is most appreciated. Best regards Kresten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wsgi file is a mess. You import `get_wsgi_application` twice, then call it before setting the environment variable; you then correctly wrap the application instance with WhiteNoise, but then throw away this instance by calling `get_wsgi_application` again.

Replace the whole thing with this:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","dagenssalg.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this tonight